# Error al poner en minúscula array

Tags: php, wordpress

No logro poner en minúscula un array asociativo, parece que array_map es solo para arrays  normales.

```
$options_variant = $options = array_map('strtolower', $options_variant);

{
  ["Stock"]=>
  string(25) "14PT Printed 1 Side (4/0)"
  ["size"]=>
  string(7) "3.5 x 2"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["Coating"]=>
  string(10) "No Coating"
  ["Round corners"]=>
  string(2) "NO"
  ["Turnaround"]=>
  string(17) "Next Business Day"
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué hay en `$options_variant` (lo puedes verificar con un **`var_dump($options_variant);`**)
? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: No me sale un error en especifico porque estoy usando wordpress

Comment: Es que en la pregunta dices *me da error*, entonces no es que dé error, será que no funciona. Sea como sea, entonces activa el modo debug de Wordpress o revisa el log de errores de PHP para ver si hay algún error en específico. Y, ¿si pones `var_dump($options_variant);` ves algo en pantalla?

Comment: Ya encontre el erro, el "array" en realidad era un objeto, lo transfomer en array y ya no da error, ahora solo me pone en misnucula el valor de la clave, me interesa que sea el nombre clave

Comment: @felixlozada a ver si entendí. ¿Quisieras pasar a minúsculas las claves del arreglo? Por ejemplo: `Stock` a `stock`

Comment: Si eso era lo que queria, lo logre con esto array_change_key_case($options_variant,CASE_LOWER);

Comment: @felixlozada, buenísmio! Sería aún mejor pudieras [edit] tu pregunta explicar mejor lo que necesitabas y si crearas una respuesta con el código que finalmente resolvio tu problema

Comment: Si, ahora lo hare

Answer (score 0):

Solucione mi problema así, este es el método correcto para poner en minúscula arrays asociativos

```
array_change_key_case($options_variant,CASE_LOWER);
```